# Power bi Gateway Refresh Limit

Tags: powerbi, azure-sql-database, powerbi-desktop

I have a SQL Server Db in on-premise.It has a gateway refresh limitation of max 48 times a day with the highest license from power Bi service.If I move the data to azure SQL database,Will it be able to refresh the dataset unlimited times a day from Power BI.

Comment: From the linked article is appears that that the 48 refreshes is for premium capacity and probably won't change.  But a little lower it states "Also note that datasets on a Premium capacity don't impose limitations for API refreshes." 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/refresh-data#configure-scheduled-refresh

Answer (score 2):

Put the data into a SQL Server Analysis Services Tabular model and set the Model and PowerBI reports to use a Direct Connection. You can refresh the SSAS model as many times as you want exceeding the 48 per times a day of limit for normal SQL Server Data sets.

Answer (score 0):

Summary from Microsoft documentation is as below-

> For Power BI users, refreshing data typically means importing data
> from the original data sources into a dataset, either based on a
> refresh schedule or on-demand. You can perform multiple dataset
> refreshes daily, which might be necessary if the underlying source
> data changes frequently. Power BI limits datasets on shared capacity
> to eight daily refreshes. If the dataset resides on a Premium
> capacity, you can schedule up to 48 refreshes per day in the dataset
> settings. Datasets on a Premium capacity with the XMLA endpoint
> enabled for read-write support unlimited refresh operations when
> configured programmatically with TMSL or PowerShell.

For more details, you can visit [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/refresh-data#:%7E:text=Power%20BI%20limits%20datasets%20on,refresh%20later%20in%20this%20article.)